# Que dire lorsque "la plupart" n'en désigne pas assez ? (des synonymes de "la plupart")

Tags: synonymes

J'ai pensé à *l'immense majorité*.

Connaissez-vous d'autres synonymes ?

Comment: La plus grande partie de …, le plus souvent, presque toujours, le plus grand nombre de … ; (pour) la plupart : quant à la majorité [de ce dont on parle] — le Petit Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On pourrait aussi dire :

- La presque totalité
- Tout le monde ou presque (en parlant de personnes)
- L'ensemble des ...
- 99% des ...

Answer (score 5):

On peut aussi dire :

- Quasiment tous (quasiment tous/toutes les...)
- La quasi-totalité
- L'écrasante majorité
- La grande masse des...

Comment: Merci beaucoup! (Comme le deux réponses sont super, et qu'il faut choisir, j'ai accepté la premiere)